# Getting Error Restoring Site Collection

Tags: site-collection, restore

I see this is a pretty common error, but I'm still not able to solve it.
I have a SharePoint 2010 site collection in my prod environment, which I backed up using the stsadm backup command, and I'm trying to restore it to my beta environment to an existing sharepoint site using stsadmin restore with the -overwrite parameter.  When I run the restore command I get this error:

> The operation that you are attempting to perform cannot be completed
>   successfull y.  No content databases in the web application were
>   available to store your sit e collection.  The existing content
>   databases may have reached the maximum numbe r of site collections, or
>   be set to read-only, or be offline, or may already con tain a copy of
>   this site collection.  Create another content database for the We b
>   application and then try the operation again.

Microsoft has 2 methods for resolution posted below, and I'm trying method 2, however that does not help:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926321

Answer (score 1):

This is SP2010 SP1 bug; once you delete the first site collection, it is not deleted. PowerShell can help you

Get the Guid using

```
 Get-SPDeletedSite
```

and then remove by

```
Remove-SPDeletedSite –Identity fc5ff8c9-2012-4fd8-b801-9a0efb0e71cd
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a duplicate of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24075/restore-spsite-to-the-same-content-database) and I think all your options are described there. 
Personally, I went through them all and decided either to overwrite an existing site collection or create a new content database just for the restored site collection.

Comment: If I understand correct, the post you refer to refers to a situation when you want to restore a site to the same content database. The case in this post involves backup from one environment and restore in another (ergo, another content database). But if a previous backup restore has been done between the environment, the I agree with you that it is a duplicate.

Comment: It does not need to be the same content database. If a site collection has been restored to another content database in the past, it cannot be restored there again (unless it overwrites the previous site collection). In the link that I provided there is a method of deleting the site collection and then removing it from deleted site collections. That's the only way for restore to succeed. I assume it's not the obvious: "The existing content databases may have reached the maximum number of site collections, or be set to read-only, or be offline".